# What are the monster roles in Monster Seeking Monster?

Tags: jackbox-party-pack-4

In the *Jackbox Party Pack 4* game, [*Monster Seeking Monster*](https://jackboxgames.com/2017/07/27/announcing-game-three-of-pp4-monster-seeking-monster/), each player is randomly assigned a Monster role at the start of each game.

Similar to [Mafia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_(party_game)) or [Werewolf](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Werewolf), each monster comes with a special ability. (For example, the Serial Killer will steal two hearts from a player after dating them twice).

**What are the monster roles in *Monster Seeking Monster*? What does each monster do?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Body Swapper**: On a FULL MOON, the Body Swapper will swap hearts (all of them) with the person they successfully date.
- **Glob**: Every time the Glob successfully dates 3 new players its heart tally doubles.
- **Invisible Person**: The Invisible Person starts the game with two bonus hearts. The Invisible Person's score is invisible, so they appear to be in last place until the end of the game.
- **Leprechaun**: Everyone who dates an unrevealed Leprechaun gets 2 fake hearts. When the Leprechaun is revealed all fake hearts disappear. At this moment, Leprechauns get 1 bonus heart for every player that drops in the rankings.
- **Monster Hunter**: At the end of the game the Monster Hunter gets a bonus heart for every time they date the monster-type they've secretly been told to hunt.
- **Mother**: The Mother receives a bonus heart every night their child does NOT get a date.
- **Mummy**: Everyone the Mummy dates becomes CURSED. Then so do the players they date. At the end of the game, Mummies steal half a heart for every cursed player. But if EVERYONE has been cursed then the curse is lifted and no hearts are stolen.
- **Robot**: The Robot loses a heart at the end of every night. But it also gains a bonus heart for every player that messages and tries to date it. At the end of the game, if the Robot comes in last place it fails to understand human emotions and destroys humanity. (Everyone loses)
- **Serial Killer**: The Serial Killer steals two hearts from a player the SECOND time they date each other.
- **Two-Faced Creep**: The Creep earns a bonus heart for every player they reject... but ONLY on nights they successfully get a date.
- **Vampire**: Everyone the vampire dates becomes a vampire. And then so do the people they date! At the end this vampire recives half a bonus heart for every vampire in the game.
- **Vengeful Ghost**: The Vengeful Ghost starts the game with a bonus heart. When the Vengeful Ghost asks someone on a date and gets rejected... that person loses a heart.
- **Ventriloquist Puppet**: Sad people love puppets. The Puppet gets a bonus heart every time they date someone that was rejected the night before.
- **Werewolf**: On a full moon werewolves get a bonus heart for dating... and then turn their date into a werewolf! But if a werewolf is rejected on a full moon they lose half a heart.
- **Witch**: The Witch takes a hair from each new player they date. When revealed, the Witch receives one bonus hear for every hair collected.
- **Zombie**: Everyone the zombie dates turns into a zombie. And then everyone new zombies date also turn into a zombie (At the end of the next night). At the end of the game, if EVERYONE has been infected, it's the end of the world and only the original zombie wins.